# I want update conda [M1,miniforge3]

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, mini-forge

I want to use python 3.10.0 and want to update my conda. But I couldn't.
I want to know how to do the upgrade.

Tryed:conda update conda, conda update -all

Enviroment:M1 Macbook Pro , Monterey 12.6

`conda info`

```
active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/t/miniforge3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/t/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/t/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /Users/t/.condarc
          conda version : 4.11.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=12.6=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /Users/t/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/t/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /Users/t/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /Users/t/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/t/miniforge3/envs
                          /Users/t/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.13 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : /Users/t/.netrc
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: The collective experience of long-term Conda users is that one shouldn't be using the **base** environment's Python for work, so you shouldn't trouble yourself with updating it. If you want newer Python, then create a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `mamba update --all --yes` instead of `conda update conda`